Generating PDF heatmaps in Matplotlib without artifacts
When using pcolormesh in Matplotlib to generate a heatmap (an MWE which generates the images in this post can be found at this gist, and I've put the code down below), some PDF viewers show a white grid (see the top left subplot of this screenshot or of the first image below) which is not visible when viewing a PNG (see instead this screenshot or the second image below).
Unfortunately I can't just use the PNG because this is going into a LaTeX document, and final PDF still has this issue even when it's the PNG that's included (meaning it's not an issue with Matplotlib's PDF generation, but rather something about the image itself that causes this).
Based on this answer I tried using edgecolors="face" (I also tried using the loop over the collections as shown in the answer, but it gave the same output), but it causes a weird effect where the edge colour seems to be shifted relative to the face colour (see this zoomed in screenshot). This shift is also present when I use shading="flat" so I don't think there's anything weird going on there.
Gouraud shading does solve this, and it's what I'm currently using as a workaround, but I'd rather avoid using interpolation if I can at all avoid it.
import numpy as np

from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

x = np.loadtxt("x.txt")
y = np.loadtxt("y.txt")
z = np.loadtxt("z.txt")

fig, [[ax_default, ax_face], [ax_face_flat, ax_gouraud]] = plt.subplots(2, 2)

ax_default.pcolormesh(x, y, z, shading="nearest")
ax_default.set_title("Nearest - None")

ax_face.pcolormesh(x, y, z, shading="nearest", edgecolors="face")
ax_face.set_title("Nearest - Face")

ax_face_flat.pcolormesh(x, y, z[:-1, :-1], shading="flat", edgecolors="face")
ax_face_flat.set_title("Flat - Face")

ax_gouraud.pcolormesh(x, y, z, shading="gouraud")
ax_gouraud.set_title("Gouraud")

fig.savefig("test.pdf")
fig.savefig("test.png")





